# Programmatically read all the processes status from /proc

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

I want to save all of the running processes' status from the /proc folder in a file. After reading some questions and answers here I think I should use the `pstatus` struct to determine which fields I want to save (correct me if I'm wrong?), but I don't know how I can efficiently loop through all of the running processes.

Comment: You "read" from /proc exactly as you'd read any other set of files and subdirectories.  Just fopen() the file(s) you're interested in and parse the text data.  Here is a great article: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8381

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to know how I can open ALL process folders. I don't wanna just open one or two.

Comment: Reading information from /proc and saving it into a file is usually done with Linux command-line tools. Do you need to write a C program that does it?

Comment: I suppose perusing the source code for `ps` might be informative, since it sounds like you're attempting to rewrite it...

Comment: @Pourya Yes I have to write a program for it to show the process in programming.

Comment: @twalberg I figured it's redundant and I wouldn't have considered doing that instead of ps if it wasn't for an assignment.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Linux process status is saved in `/proc/PID/status` pseudo-file and represented in textual form (other OS have completely different structure of their procfs):

```
$ grep State /proc/self/status
State:  R (running)
```

So you need a "parser" for that file:

```
void print_status(long tgid) {
    char path[40], line[100], *p;
    FILE* statusf;

    snprintf(path, 40, "/proc/%ld/status", tgid);

    statusf = fopen(path, "r");
    if(!statusf)
        return;

    while(fgets(line, 100, statusf)) {
        if(strncmp(line, "State:", 6) != 0)
            continue;
        // Ignore "State:" and whitespace
        p = line + 7;
        while(isspace(*p)) ++p;

        printf("%6d %s", tgid, p);
        break;
    }

    fclose(statusf);
}
```

To read all processes you have to use `opendir()`/`readdir()`/`closedir()` and open only directories that have numerical characters (other are sysctl variables, etc.):

```
DIR* proc = opendir("/proc");
struct dirent* ent;
long tgid;

if(proc == NULL) {
    perror("opendir(/proc)");
    return 1;
}

while(ent = readdir(proc)) {
    if(!isdigit(*ent->d_name))
        continue;

    tgid = strtol(ent->d_name, NULL, 10);

    print_status(tgid);
}

closedir(proc);
```

Alternatively, you may use [procps](http://procps.sourceforge.net/) tools which already implemented it.

Answer (score 3):

This snippet below invokes two C programs that do just that:

```
find /proc -maxdepth 2 -wholename '/proc/[0-9]*/status'  | xargs cat
```

Comment: Though, to be honest, a third C program in the form of a shell is required to spawn the above C programs and set up the pipe between them.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but still definitely a relevant one.

**If you don't want to mess with parsing procfs yourself, you should definitely check out [pfs](https://github.com/dtrugman/pfs)**. It a library for parsing most of procfs written in C++. *(Disclaimer: I'm the author of the library)*

On a Linux system, every task (process or thread) has an entry under the `/procfs` directory.

When enumerating the directories under `/procfs` you'll get a directory for each running processes.
Under each directory, you can find two files: `stat` and `status`, that include the current process status.

The possible statuses are described (almost correctly) under man proc(5):

```
(3) state  %c
    One of the following characters, indicating process state:

    R  Running

    S  Sleeping in an interruptible wait

    D  Waiting in uninterruptible disk sleep

    Z  Zombie

    T  Stopped (on a signal) or (before Linux 2.6.33) trace stopped

    t  Tracing stop (Linux 2.6.33 onward)

    W  Paging (only before Linux 2.6.0)

    X  Dead (from Linux 2.6.0 onward)

    x  Dead (Linux 2.6.33 to 3.13 only)

    K  Wakekill (Linux 2.6.33 to 3.13 only)

    W  Waking (Linux 2.6.33 to 3.13 only)

    P  Parked (Linux 3.9 to 3.13 only)
```

This is almost correct, because there's an additional possible value that is missing from this list:

```
    I  Idle
```

If you want to get the value from `stat`, the simplest way to go is probably use as `fopen` & `fscanf`. The format is intimately described under man proc(5) as well. **Note:** Just be carefull with the `comm` value format. They say it's `%s`, but it's actually much more complicated, since it might include spaces or any other character, it might screw up your parser (one more reason to use a mature parsing library).

If you want to get the value from `status`, you should probably open the file using `std::ifstream` or something like that and use `std::getline` till the lines starts with `Status:`, and then extract the value you want.